alternative code style than if/else for configurable code
I'm developing for a minecraft server written in Kotlin. The current issue I'm running into is if there is a better programming pattern than if/else blocks for mechanics that can be controlled/configured by the user.
Here's a snippet, it was suggested that one of the controller mechanics (drifting) be able to be toggled by the user.
    fun setDirectControlEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        isDirectControlEnabled = enabled
        if (enabled) {
            sendMessage(dcMessage)

            val player: Player = (controller as? PlayerController)?.player ?: return

            player.walkSpeed = 0.009f
            val playerLoc = player.location
            directControlCenter = playerLoc.toBlockLocation().add(0.5, playerLoc.y.rem(1)+0.001, 0.5)
            if(!PlayerCache[player].playerConfig.dcDrift) { // the configuration to check
                player.teleport(directControlCenter!!) // the code to run
            }//skipping the teleportation causes the user to drift
     // more code 

The suggested snippet isnt too bad, but as more settings are added, or there are nested settings, Im worried that the codebase will be become muddled with code that mostly covers setting control than actually handling the intended mechanic.

if (configOne) {
    // do something
    if (configTwo) {
        // also do 
   }
} else {
   //do this instead
}


Is there a code style/pattern that minimizes obfuscation?
I've tried looking into decorators and annotations, although both of those things don't seem like the thing I want.

I think just extract each config check into its own method is enough to reduce the nesting.

I don't know how to avoid nesting in your case, but maybe it will be enough for you if no one comes along with better idea.
If you want the code to be easy to read, you can extract implementation for each condition into different methods and call those methods in those nested ifs.
For example:
fun main() {
    val configOne = true // just to initialize the variable for this demo
    val configTwo = false // just to initialize the variable for this demo
    
    if (configOne) {
        doSomething1()
        if (configTwo) {
            doSomething2()
        }
    } else {
        doSomething3()
    }
}

fun doSomething1() {
    //do sth
}

fun doSomething2() {
    //do sth
}

fun doSomething3() {
    //do sth
}


Can't you make ConfigOne,two three extend a parent class and create a child for it in run time and just say COnfig.execute()?
ConfigOne extends Config
ConfigTwo extends Config
ConfigThree extends Config
Have a factor class which returns isntance of one of the three classes and call execute method.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
